# Pouchdb. How to verify a doc is replicated

Tags: pouchdb

Im using poychdb basically to let a mobile user create sales orders offline, then later replicate them to central couchdb server, then process them there on a cron job basis.

As replication can sync some docs...then stop (lost Internet. ..) i need a way to block the mobile user from editing those already synced orders. But hd can still edit other non-yet-uploaded orders

There is some way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `replicate()` function returns an event emitter which emits a `'change'` event: http://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication.

So you can listen for `'change'` events, which will tell you how many documents were written and the `seq` (update sequence #) of the last written document. Using the changes feed and the `since` parameter, you can figure out which documents were already written to the remote database.

E.g. if the `last_seq` is 50, then `changes({since: 50})` will give you all documents that haven't been synced yet.

Comment: The `last_seq` from the `complete` event, is saved somewhere to be queried, or should i save it for later use it as the `since` parameter on the `changes` call?

BTW, i'm not using live replication, so i can safely use just the `complete` event, not the `change`, right?

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong, but both `changes` and `complete` return...

`{ pull { ... }, push: { ... } }`

Which one last_seq should i use on this case? `info.pull.last_seq` ? or `info.push.last_seq`?

Comment: I added a longer comment in the GH issue you opened: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/2521