# Find replicated docs cblite

Tags: android, couchdb

How to find out whether a document from a cblite database has been replicated on android with the help of cblite api?
Came across this link but couldn't make any sense out of it.
[Pouchdb. How to verify a doc is replicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899938/pouchdb-how-to-verify-a-doc-is-replicated)

Comment: is there any reserved property the document has to indicate whether its replicated For eg _deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cblite db each document has a sequence number, whenever each document gets replicated a sequence number is assigned to the document. Here's piece of code to get a better understanding,

```
//Get the latest sequence number of the document replicated
lastSeq = rep.getLastSequence();

Query query = database.createAllDocumentsQuery();
QueryEnumerator rowEnum = query.run();


for (Iterator<QueryRow> it = rowEnum; it.hasNext();) {
                QueryRow row = it.next();
                if(lastSequence!=null)
                {
                    if(Long.parseLong(lastSequence)>=row.getSequenceNumber())
                    {
                        purgeDoc = row.getDocument();
                        purgeDoc.purge();
                    }
                }
            }
```